# QuickFIX/J: Is there any way to modify the logon response sent by the server

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am building a FIX adapter and the server I am hitting to response with `1137=FIX.5.0SP2`.
My understanding is that `1137/DefaultApplVerId` should be an enum. And QuickFIX/J throws up because it is expecting an enum value like `9`.

```
13:46:00.628 [NioProcessor-12] ERROR quickfixj.errorEvent - org.quickfixj.QFJException: Unknown or unsupported ApplVerID: FIX.5.0SP2
org.quickfixj.QFJException: Unknown or unsupported ApplVerID: FIX.5.0SP2
```

Since I have no control over how the server responds. So my question is if there is any way for me to intercept and modify the response before it gets parsed by QuickFIX/J?

Comment: Which version of QFJ are you using? Can you post the message log before receiving that message?

Comment: And yes, actually ApplVerID is an enum with integer values but datatype is a String, so maybe your counterparty misunderstood. Did you try to approach your counterparty? Maybe they can correct it.

Comment: I am using QFJ 2.1.0
I worked around the issue for now by setting the targetDefaultApplicationVersionId in the toAdmin method
I dug through the source code and found that it checks for this first before looking in the message header.
        
--session.setTargetDefaultApplicationVersionID(new ApplVerID("9"));--

I am continuing with this for now, but i am not sure if there will be any future issues due to this.

Comment: OK, good to know. If there are any issues then get in touch.